# how to show viewed recently products in default.xml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

i tried many things to display recently viewed products in header section but it's not appearing :(

default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="page.top" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="cms_page" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="page.bottom.container" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="before.body.end" remove="true"/>
        <move element="minicart" destination="holder" />

        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="custom.header" label="navbar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="navbar">
                <block name='holder' class="Main\Store\Block\TheHeader" template="Magento_Theme::header_holder.phtml">


                </block>

            </container>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer htmlClass='container-fluid' name="footer-container">
            <block name="my-footer" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::footer.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>


    </body>
</page>
```